# is Http Web Request safe?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am using C# in order to build a simple desktop application that withdraws data from a web page I have.

I am using (HTTP Web Request) method and want to make sure that it is a safe method ? I mean could anyone be able to "Hack it" if its the right word to say ?

ex. I am bringing some strings from this web page I have and I want to process these strings on the client side and show it to the client, can anyone log to my Http Web Request and change these strings then send them to my client ?

sorry if my question is silly , But I have to make sure its safe . . .

if its not safe . do you suggest any other way ?

Comment: You should use an HTTPS connection to connect to the website.

Comment: how can I do that ? I mean is there a specific method

Comment: The server needs to support HTTPS :-)

Comment: ahhh , if the server where I host my page supported HTTPS and I used HTTP Web Request then it will be safe ?

Comment: Safer than without HTTPS, yes. I guess there would be tons of possible security issues. I'm no expert at all, if you _really_ need security I would expect to contact a security consulting company and let them do a review of your code or help you when designing the architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using HTTPS (or some other similar method), then yes, anyone between the computer your application is running on and the server you're downloading from could capture your transmission and reply acting as the server.

That being said, unless you're transmitting sensitive or valuable information (e.g. credit card numbers) it's unlikely this is going to happen to you.

Comment: and how can I use https in such way ?

Comment: @Mouayad, that depends on the server. If it doesn't support HTTPS, then you simply don't have other option than to be insecure. If it supports HTTPS, it usually means just replacing `http://` with `https://`.

Comment: and if I used a server that supports https ? then all I have to do is this replacement ? I mean it will make it secure ?

Comment: @Mouayad, almost. To be absolutely sure, I think you would have to implement your own [`ICertificatePolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icertificatepolicy.aspx) to check that the certificate hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Since it will be an object local to your application, it's as safe as you allow it to be. Without seeing how you're attempting to use it it's going to be difficult to further assist you.